# Call Apple-specific OpenGL commands through MonoTouch/OpenTK

Tags: xamarin.ios, opengl-es-2.0, opentk

If I understand things correctly, Apple's OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation uses some methods from OpenGL ES 3.0, for example

```
glBindVertexArrayAPPLE
```

or

```
glBindVertexArrayOES
```

instead of

```
glBindVertexArray
```

It seems that the OpenTK compilation that gets delivered with MonoTouch does not include either of these methods, although there exist OpenTK bindings for them, see for example line 229 of http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/_g_l_core_8cs_source.html.

**Is there any way I can use these features in MonoTouch? Maybe some way to call them through a P/Invoke?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things clear, `OpenTK-1.0.dll` as shipped with MonoTouch since early 2012 (no need to install anything else), supports `glBindVertexArrayOES` by calling:

```
GL.Oes.BindVertexArray([u]int);
```

No additional p/invoke is required in user code. As for `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE`, which would *logically* be available as:

```
GL.Apple.BindVertexArray([u]int);
```

it is **not** part of the API since `GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object` is not defined in the iOS version of `glext.h` (like it is for OSX version of the same file). Note that `GL_OES_vertex_array_object` is defined in both iOS and OSX versions of `glext.h` which is why the *Oes* API is available.

A quick grep (to find all occurances) did not show the symbols as available in any of the .dylib (so adding it or p/invoking it would fail at runtime).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. If `OpenTK-1.0.dll` ships together with MonoTouch, maybe you should give it another version number than 0.0.0.0 (it appears as 0.0.0.0 in my installation). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

That's it:

```
[DllImport(Constants.OpenGLESLibrary, EntryPoint="glGenVertexArraysOES")]
public extern static void GenVertexArrays(int n, out int id);

[DllImport(Constants.OpenGLESLibrary, EntryPoint="glBindVertexArrayOES")]
public extern static void BindVertexArray(int id);
```

There are more functions like these two. @Xamarin, maybe they could be included in the next MonoTouch release?

Comment: I see both `glBindVertexArray` abnd `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE` but not `glBindVertexArrayOES`. I'll add them (let us know if you thru bugzilla if you find any other issing pieces). Thanks!

Comment: Rolf was *right* if a bit imprecise. The p/invoke itself is in `OpenTK-1.0.dll` but it's `internal` not `public`. However you should be able to reach it by using `GL.Oes.BindVertexArray(int)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will, but it's strange that I do not see `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE`. I'm using MD 3.0.6 with Mono 2.10.9 and MonoTouch 6.0.8, but my OpenTK-1.0.dll has version 0.0.0.0. Please have a look at this screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35614983/opentk_0000.png How can I install the current version of OpenTK? Doesn't it install automatically with MonoTouch?

Comment: Cheers, now I'm using `GL.Oes.BindVertexArray(int)`, as you suggested. Still can't find `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE` though, there isn't a `GL.Apple.BindVertexArray(int)`.

Comment: It's in the sources but I don't see it in the binary using MD's assembly browser. I'll look into it.

Comment: I cannot find `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE` in iOS header files, only in OSX. Have you any klink saying this is available for iOS developers ? or any other reason to use this one over the others ?

Comment: Sorry, I searched Google and found both `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE` and `glBindVertexArrayOES`. I didn't realize the difference. `glBindVertexArrayOES` is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you reference OpenTK-1.0 instead of OpenTK you will find this API there.

Comment: I am using OpenTK-1.0.dll, but it's not there, I have to manually p/invoke it. I'm using the latest MonoTouch/MonoDevelop version, only few days ago I received an update.